# OpenShift: Cronjob is executed in wrong timezone despite master configuration is correct

Tags: cron, kubernetes, timezone

I have a configured a cronjob in OpenShift. Its crontab entry looks like this:

```
spec:
  schedule: "0 3 * * 1-5"
  jobTemplate:
```

So it should run at 03:00 in the morning on weekdays. All cluster nodes are configured to use our local timezone, CET, which is UTC+1. This is visible via the `date` command. OpenShift documentation says that cronjobs are executed via the crontab matching the configured time zone of the master nodes, so i expect the cronjobs to actually run at 03:00 CET.

However, according to the logs, the cronjobs are executed at 04:00 which is 03:00 CET in UTC. The strange part is that `oc describe cronjob` reveals:

```
Last Schedule Time:  Mon, 14 Jan 2019 04:00:00 +0100
```

So, the server actually knows that the cronjob is executed one hour too late.

My question is: Why is the cronjob executed one hour too late, why does the server know about it, and how can i fix this?

Comment: Check the system timezone of your master nodes.

Comment: They are configured as CET as well.

Answer (score 6):

CronJobs are controlled by the master-controller.

In Openshift (after ~v3.10), the controllers are run as a pod, defined in `/etc/origin/node/pods` (at least in our setup).

We had the exact same problem and noticed that the timestamp in controller-logs was one hour off.

This was fixed by adding a mount in `/etc/origin/node/pods/controller.yaml`

Under `volumeMounts:`, add:

```
   - mountPath: /etc/localtime
      name: localtime
```

Under `volumes:`, add:

```
  - hostPath:
      path: /etc/localtime
    name: localtime
```